# Map view not showing exact location needs to zoom out

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am new to ios and working on map view i have showned position on map view (Annotation)using lat, long. map view is showing location, but need to do pinching to get exact location.(zoom with two fingures) I am using following code but it not showing exact location for exact location i need to use zoom then is showing exact location but i want to display it without touching to map view??

```
zoomLocation.latitude = latmpa.doubleValue;
zoomLocation.longitude = logmpa.doubleValue;
annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = zoomLocation;
annotationPoint.title = @"masjid....";
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];

[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

mapView.centerCoordinate = annotationPoint.coordinate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work out the region you want the map to be looking at and then use `[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES]` [ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion%3aanimated%3a).

An [MKCoordinateRegion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKCoordinateRegion) is made of a [CLLocationCoordinate2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocationCoordinate2D) which you've already made and a [MKCoordinateSpan](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html). Here's an example of making a span

```
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 1.5;
span.longitudeDelta = 1.0;
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center = zoomLocation;
newRegion.span = span;
[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
```